# C++ Include paths w/ clang on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, path, clang, llvm, freebsd

How should I include standard and not-standard libraries in c++ programms for clang on freeBSD?
With standard I mean things like `<iostream>` with non-standard I mean things like `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp`.

I am lost on my path in freebsd 13.0.
So far I used `cc` (clang) to compile `c` programs. To include port libraries I use `cc src.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib`. This works for me and I get to do my things.

Now I want to compile a c++ program and I can not figure out what I am missing.
Currently I did get a simple `hello world` to work.
Trying to compile:

```cpp
//hello.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
std::cout << "Hello.\n";
}
```

With `cc -cc1 hello.cpp -ast-print` I get

```
clang -cc1 version 11.0.1 based upon LLVM 11.0.1 default target x86_64-unknown-freebsd13.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/clang/11.0.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
hello.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
int main() {
}
1 error generated.
```

I can `locate iostream` at `/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream`
And include it in the path with `-I/usr/include/c++/v1`.
But then it becomes a bit messy. And I can not locate the respective library for `-L`

How should I include these things? I am a bit confused as I thought at this stage I only use utilities from the freeBSD base system, which would be on the default path anyway.

Comment: Clang has several aliases, `cc` invokes its C persona, use `c++` for C++ source files. For example: `c++ hello.cpp` generates your test program as `a.out`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. `c++ hello.cpp` prints 44398 lines on my terminal of what looks like c++ code with a lot of `extern template  class __attribute__ (([...]`. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind. the `c++ hello.cpp` works. I don't know what I messed up 2h ago.